# Extract posts title from JSON returned data

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I am not sure why this isn't working. I want to show the post title, excepts on my blog page but I am not getting any of the objects displayed. This is my code:

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function() {     
        //$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();    
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=recentstories&callback=",
                dataType: "json",
                jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); },
                complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },
                success:function(data){

                console.log(data.posts);
                alert (data.posts.length);

                 },
                error: function (request,error) {
                alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
            }
        });
    });
```

This is what my console shows:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

When I expand the first object, I see the different elements I want. How so I expand down each object to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Those are also objects, try iterating through them:

```
console.log(data.posts);
for (var i = 0; i < data.posts.length; i++) {
    //Just the title
    console.log(data.posts[i].title);

    //Iterate all the keys
    for (var key in data.posts[i]) {
        console.log(data.posts[i][key]);
    }
}
```